# What is the combination of Wind Style and Earth Style?

Tags: naruto

After quite some research, I've found this picture, and I've added/completed the combinations. As you can see, I've found all of the combinations (even if some of you wouldn't agree with me), but I have absolutely no idea what should be put as the combination of Wind and Earth...

I forgot to mention that there is one style, the Crystal Release, whose origins are unclear to me. It may be the response to the question, but I've got no proof or source to claim it.

[image]

Comment: You didn't leave the question marks next to the specific unconfirmed releases, such as blaze, scorch, magnet, and explosion release. For example, Blaze release has to do with the Mangekyou black flames and there is no indication that Lightning is required here.

Comment: you're right, as for those 4 I've deleted the question mark,since on Narutopedia,and other site, all of the questioners, who were interested in the combinations,agreed,that even if in the pic is with a question mark,we're almost 100% sure, that those combinations are made from the basic styles,as it is shown in this image

Comment: What would be the argument that Amaterasu flames uses Lightning? Or how Explosion uses Lightning? I would expect Explosion to use fire. This diagram is more speculation and people wanting it to work out. Magnet was completely speculated as well.

Comment: it's said,that "It is unknown what element(s) this nature entails aside from Fire Release which makes up Amaterasu". I'd say,that even if it's stated,that the Blaze Style is "an advanced chakra nature kekkei genkai of the Uchiha clan",the only person seen and known using it it's not Shisui or Itachi or a random Uchiha guy, but Sasuke. Since the styles used by him are fire and lightning, that it's why I would bet,that the other style used in Blaze it's the lightning

Comment: now I see your explosion questions...if I recall well, Deidara was an advanced user of explosion style, one of this component it's surely the Earth style, and maybe it's speculation,but since there wouldn't be a proper spot for it, and if you think,that lightning could be involved in explosion, you would say,even it's speculation, that the Explosion style uses earth AND lightning....I see that you too don't agree with me xD

Comment: @Rinneg4n Lightning was the weakness of the explosion style. I dont see lightning canceling out lightning.

Comment: Simply Mud-balls! Or maybe Sandstorms?

Answer (score 3):

The effect you are asking for is not yet known, just like how some of the others in the chart are not confirmed or not complete (such as Blaze, Storm and Explosion).

The chart is set-up with the current knowledge we have of the techniques and filling in the blanks by deducing what could be in the slot. Most of them might actually prove to be accurate, but until this is confirmed in either the anime or manga we won't know for sure.

Comment: Magnet wasn't exactly confirmed either. Wind and Lightning as magnet is also just a speculation.

Comment: @krikara Actually 1 of the required elements is confirmed, which is earth, although in this scheme that is not even attached to it.

Comment: as I've mentioned in the question,"even if some of you wouldn't agree with me".I don't want to argue with none of you, I know that there are truly some Styles,which aren't confirmed,but as @Dimitri mx stated:"Is set-up with the current knowledge we have of the technique's and filling in the blanks by deducing what could be in the slot.".I've been thinking on this chart, because it's an interesting fact,which combination are made by which basic styles, and even if it's not legit, it's curiosity that led me to ask about this,and I know,there are other guys,who really like this kind of "riddles".

Answer (score 2):

I just read your question and saw your graph. Got to say, nice work.

Though, I would make some changes:

- Blaze Release: Should be an advance version of Fire release, not a combination of Fire and Lightning release.
- Magnet Release: This is my own opinion, but I think this is more of an Earth and Lightning release.

As for your actual question, I would fill in the blank in the diagram with Sand Release. Let me explain my choice:

I know that Shukaku has the Magnet release, but the Mizukage proved that even a regular shinobi can have more than one Kekkei Genkai, so why not a Tailed Beast? Also there's the fact that the Third and Fourth Kazekage used their Magnet release to mimic Shukaku's sand. Although sand does have *some* magnetic minerals inside of it, these minerals will just slide past the rest when they come in contact of an actual magnet. So, in conclusion, my theory is that the Kazekage couldn't manipulate sand because it's not a magnet type element.

One may argue that the reason why the Kazekage didn't manipulate regular sand is because iron sand and gold dust is heavier. However, I would say that regular sand is more versatile and plentiful. There are oceans of sand, and they are not completely made out of metal. Sand is a mixture of all types of minerals that have been broken down to the size of a grain. In fact, Gaara himself once said that he uses his sand to dig underground, find the hardest minerals, crush them, and then mix them into the sand to make it stronger. Sand release makes more sense for Wind and Earth combination, since it's a product of weathering and erosion. So instead of being a magnetic type element, it's a deposition type element.

This doesn't mean that Gaara is weak compared to his predecessors. Since it's lighter, it's also quicker and more likely to be easier to control. Also, it's easier to produce, you can turn just about any kind of rock into sand. On the other hand, you can't turn sand or just any kind of rock into iron or gold without going through a molecular process. While his father used the gold dust to way Gaara down, Gaara could simply use his sand to gather the dust, take the infected sand, and bury it before making more sand from his environment. Of course, this all depends on who's better with their ninjutsu.

Therefore, I firmly believe that Earth + Wind = Sand.

Answer (score 2):

**Wind Release** and **Earth Release** make **Magnet Release**. Take a look at the [*combined nature transformation relationships*](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_Transformation#Combined_Nature_Transformations) image taken from wikia. The image is kinda small and blurry, don't mind if I modify your image to match wikia's image.

[image]

Well, the question has been answered, but I bet you still arguing about what's the replacement of **Blaze Release** and the old **Magnet Release**.

**[Blaze Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Blaze_release#Blaze_Release)** is a **Kekkei Genkai**, but it doesn't work with mixing one type of elemental chakra with another, like mixing **Fire Relase** and **Lightning Release**. In fact, it's a highest level **Fire Release** Ninjutsu, only acquired through wielding the *Mangekyō Sharingan*.

**[Fire Release + Lightning Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kirin)** wasn't an official combination of *Ninjutsu* of forming a *Kekkei Genkai*, but it can be used in conjunction with **Lightning Release** to alter weather conditions to create an extremely powerful **Lightning Release**, the ***Kirin***.

**[Wind Release + Lightning Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_and_Lightning_Release:_Typhoon_Lightning_Spiral)** wasn't an official combination of *Ninjutsu* of forming a *Kekkei Genkai*, but it doesn't mean that the combination hasn't been used in *Naruto Shippuden Franchise*. In the game *Naruto Shippūden: Ultimate Ninja Storm Revolution*, Naruto forms a wind-natured *Rasengan* and Sasuke adds his *Chidori* to the sphere, forming ***Wind Release Lightning Release: Typhoon Lightning Spiral***, a type of *[Cooperation Ninjustu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Cooperation_Ninjutsu)*, which means a collaboration of two or more *Ninjutsu* to create a new *Ninjutsu* with a greater strength.

**[Crystal Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Crystal_Release)** though, **Earth Release** may be a presumed component element. For more information, go click the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

There is no known technique that can be derived from the combination of Earth and Wind release but what I have is a theory:

The combination of Wind and Earth **can be** the following:

- **Swift Release** - an advanced nature Kekkei Genkai that can be used to
  move at virtually instantaneous speed, granting the user an advantage
  over opponents with more strength than speed, such as users of Chakra
  Enhanced Strength. This nature therefore renders the user
  invulnerable against most taijutsu.
- **Steel Release** - an advanced nature
  Kekkei Genkai that can be used to make one's body virtually
  indestructible by turning it into black steel.

I don't include Magnet release because I have a very minimal evidence that the user of this style (Toroi and the two Kazekage) has Earth and Wind release. On the other hand, since [Hiruko](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiruko_(missing-nin)) is the only ninja I know that has a Earth and Wind type elements release, he can combine the two elements to form a new release like the two I mentioned. I also presume that the technique/release is also a Kekkei Genkai.

Comment: it's this Steel Release the style that Kakuzu used?

Comment: Not only kakuzu but also others like Hikuro.

Answer (score 1):

Magnet Release is a combination of Earth and Wind. Gaara's father has Wind, Water and Earth natures. Wind and Water creates Ice. Water and Earth creates Wood. Therefore, the only possible combination left for Magnet Release is Wind and Earth.

Blaze Release is not a combination of Fire and Lightning. It's just Fire. Sasuke creates the black flames of Amaterasu with his left eye and controls them with his right eye, so it does not come from a combination of natures, but just a Mangekyo ability.

Swift Release is combination of Wind and Lightning, since both elements can be used to increase one's speed.

Comment: Could you possible site your sources for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a pure speculation, but, if you have a chunk of Earth, and you separate it into very small pieces and let it fly using Wind release, wouldn't that end up as Sand? Or at least sand-like. So I think the combination of Earth and Wind is Sand Release.

This fits as Yamato explained before, that since he can use Wood Release, he can also use Water and Earth release. Shukaku can use Wind Release too and sand is pretty much Earth, so for Sand Release he uses both Wind and Earth release.

Answer (score 0):

Earth plus wind equals weathering swift and dark don’t come from weathing and neither does steel but Crystals can be a result of weathering so wind and earth is crystal

Comment: And what do you base this answer on? Do you happen to have canon sources to back this up ?

Answer (score -2):

wouldnt it be crystal style? Since that's the only one not shown and sasuke doesn't use fire or lightning for his blaze style he uses his left to shoot the flames and the right to control them

Comment: Crystal Is anime only and was never explained, so it cant fit into the diagram anywhere naturally